# EF TPT Creating and Reading

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have an order class with has a collection of products...

```
public class Order
{
    int id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Product
{
    int id { get; set; }
}
```

Derived from product, I have several different types of product...

```
public class ProductA : Product
{
    public string CustomFieldA {get; set;}
}

public class ProductB : Product
{
    public string CustomFieldB {get; set;}
}
```

I can add these derived products to the order and save them to the database...

```
var producta = new ProductA();
producta.CustomFieldA = "abc";
order.Products.Add(product);
order.SaveChanges();
```

This updates the database correctly.

What I can't then figure out is how I access this data!

Order.Products just contains the base class, how can I check which type of derived class each record in Order.Products is and access, for example, CustomFieldA of any that are ProductA.

I suspect either I'm missing something really obvious, or I've done the first part completely wrong!

Comment: did you try to use `OfType` ? Something like `[Order.Products].OfType<ProductA>().Select(x => x.CustomFieldA)` ?

Comment: Thanks, OfType is what I was missing! I knew it must be something simple!